# Jquery Event Based off filling out data

Tags: jquery

I have 4 dropdown boxes on a page that are reliant on the previous dropdown.

```
D1 > D2 > D3 > D4
```

BackStory:

The idea is d1 triggers d2 which triggers d3 which triggers d4. The way im programming this ( not my choice but a requirement) is that i give the database the sql query and when it returns the info it populates the dropdown. This means that if I call d1 it sends off that database query and before the database responds it is trying to send off the database query for d2. Since d2 is reliant on d1 this errors out because d1 is still null or the previous value.

Question:
Is there a way i can use jquery to fire off an event when a dropdown's data changes.

More Info

I already have a .change() on all the dropdowns but those seem tied to the user changing them. Im even open to suggesetions on how to do this different so it works. The main idea behind this is any one of the 4 dropdowns can change. If D3 is changed then D4 needs to change if D2 is changed then D3 and D4 need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there a way i can use jquery to fire off an event when a dropdown's data changes?"

yes, kind of. assuming a function is changing that data, after you've updated the data you can use that function to fire the change event as if the user did. Lets say you want this to fire for D2

```
function updateData(){
  get data for D2; //obvious psuedo code
  update data for D2; //obvious psuedo code
  $('#D2').change(); //jquery fired the change on the dropdown as if the user made the change
}
```